# A dialog has a delay to open, I get an error when navigating to another view before the dialog is generated. How can I make it not be generated?

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter.

In my real problem, my client is in places where it is very frequent that the internet is very slow, so sometimes an attempt is made to make a web request and this may take time, so the user leaves the screen before the web request is completed. Sometimes my app after completing a web request generates a `dialog`. So here is where my problem lies, the user is trying to make a web request and while it is done, they leave the screen and then the `dialog` is generated.

I am trying to simulate this problem with a `delay` that later generates the `dialog`.

I am not thinking of any strategy to end the web request, what I want is to find a way that once I leave the screen, causes the dialog not to be generated something like a `dispose`

I made an example where I have 2 screens. On the second screen a dialog is generated with a delay of 5 seconds when the button is clicked. If I navigate to another screen before the dialog is opened I get an error. I assume this occurs because the view was destroyed and therefore the dialog cannot be opened.

[image]

What can I do to avoid the error when the dialog is generated after being in another view? if I am in another view I DO NOT WANT the dialog to be generated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("main");
    return MaterialApp(title: 'Provider Example', initialRoute: '/', routes: {
      '/': (context) => Home(),
      'home': (context) => Home(),
      'dialogpage': (context) => Dialogpage(),
    });
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Home() {
    print("home");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('home'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add_alert),
            tooltip: 'Show Snackbar',
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, "dialogpage");
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'home',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Dialogpage extends StatelessWidget {
  Dialogpage() {
    print("dialogpage");
  }

  dialog(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
              title: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(19.0),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(19.0),
                  ),
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 5),
                child: Text(
                  'Error',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              content: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.error,
                      size: 50,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("dialog"),
                ],
              ),
              titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Aceptar'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      return Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    }),
              ],
            );
          });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('dialog'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("show dialog"),
            onPressed: () {
              dialog(context);
            }),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Globalkey in scaffold in then check the context in dialog method is it != null
then run dialog otherwise don't...

```
  GlobalKey _scafolldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
        key: _scafolldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('dialog'),),
            body: Center(
                child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("show dialog"),
                    onPressed: () {
                    dialog(context);
               }),
            ),
         );
       }
    }

    dialog(BuildContext context) {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
          if(_scafolldKey.currentContext !=null){
          showDialog();
            }
         });  
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Future.delayed`, you should use `Timer`, which can be cancelled in `onDispose` method.

**Working solution:**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("main");
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Provider Example',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => Home(),
        'home': (context) => Home(),
        'dialogpage': (context) => Dialogpage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Home() {
    print("home");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('home'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add_alert),
            tooltip: 'Show Snackbar',
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, "dialogpage");
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'home',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Dialogpage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DialogpageState createState() => _DialogpageState();
}

class _DialogpageState extends State<Dialogpage> {
  Timer _timer;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  dialog(BuildContext context) {
    _timer = Timer(
      const Duration(seconds: 3),
      () {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
              title: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(19.0),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(19.0),
                  ),
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 5),
                child: Text(
                  'Error',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              content: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.error,
                      size: 50,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("dialog"),
                ],
              ),
              titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Aceptar'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    return Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('dialog'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("show dialog"),
          onPressed: () {
            dialog(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
class Dialogpage extends StatelessWidget {
  ...
  Timer t;

  dialog(BuildContext context) {
    t = Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      showDialog(...);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('dialog'),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
          onPressed: () {
            t?.cancel();
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("show dialog"),
            onPressed: () {
              dialog(context);
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.